# Gist support for chat 'onebox'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

It would be very helpful on question chats (when they go live) to have gist 'onebox' support, to make it easy to share code.

Comment: or better still an internal gist like construct for chat

Comment: @Jeff If gist is `[status-planned]`, what about other services such as pastie or pastebin?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding waffles♦'s comment,

You can write multi-line messages with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Moreover, you can just paste multi-line messages and they will be formatted as monospaced automatically (example: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/5211).

However, there's no code highlighting.

Comment: The useful part of gists is that there is syntax highlighting already there.

Comment: @phsr: Syntax highlighting is [a different issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57078/syntax-highlighting-for-chat).