# Syntax highlighting for chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, syntax-highlighting

I noticed that syntax highlighting isn't enabled for [chat.meta.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com).

Here is a good example:  http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/5365

Comment: I can't get to either of your links.

Comment: Because it requires a password?  If so, check the blog.

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57041/gist-support-for-chat-onebox

Comment: @phsr: It is **not** a dupe. In this context we want highlighting for code that appears directly in a message, not something from another site.

Comment: A user made this for the PHP room https://gist.github.com/connorGFX/5891914 and this for the JS room https://gist.github.com/connorGFX/5891838 I've been using it for almost a year, and it works amazing. Hopefully, SO will get onboard and add syntax highlighting to chat.

Answer (score 1):

<s>This is by design for now -- we aren't doing syntax highlighting of code in chat.</s>

However, we do support oneboxing of gists:

http://gist.github.com/509368

Comment: I'm not trying to be impolite, but I would really like to know the reason behind that decision. Is it because it's too JS-heavy for a chat, or something like that?

Comment: 7 years 7 months later.. still wondering why have we been forsaken in chat