# Offer a Stack Exchange-brand "pastebin"

Tags: feature-request, code

Following on from [this Meta TeX SE question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/625/215), how about offering an SE-branded pastebin for posting long files? The problem with using things like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) is that files get deleted after some time. Since the idea of these sites is to build a repository of questions and answers, it's no good for our answers rely on broken links.

Ideally, "SE pastebin" would have the following features:

- Items not linked to by questions/answers on any SE site would be deleted.
- Users would be able to control when files expire (e.g. if you're posting output from `dmesg` or the like, that can expire when you accept a solution, but if the text is, say, code used in the answer, then that should never expire).
- Users should be able to specify syntax highlighting.

Comment: This is a brilliant idea.

Comment: Nice idea. Maybe license / rent / buy a good existing implementation, like they did with Imgur for inline images?

Comment: I like this, would be great for "oneboxing" in chat and, if it were integrated with WMD (like Imgur), it just might solve those rough syntax highlighting issues.

Comment: Expiration is a bad idea. Why remove context from a question/answer?

Comment: We'd have to encourage people to include the relevant lines of the dmesg output in their answer: the rest of the file is irrelevant. I guess hosting text is so cheap nowadays that there's no cost issue in keeping it around forever... (that was what motivated the ideas about expiration)

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but what is "oneboxed"?

Comment: I really discourage the use of externale (pastebin-like) sites as they tend to break over time. Questions / answers / effort is renderd useless due to external sites rearranging their content. I think it is time for paste.stackexchange.com

Comment: This should happen automatically when code pasted in an answer/question exceeds a certain size.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's already something matching what you're looking for: [Github Gist](http://gist.github.com).

- They are already oneboxed in chat.
- They make a *real* git repository for each post.
- They allow editing posts (which translates to a `git commit` behind the scenes).
- They allow anonymous posting.
- They do syntax highlighting.
- They allow multiple files.
- They allow comments with Markdown syntax.

Here's [a complex example.](https://gist.github.com/631092)

Comment: I don't know how you went from "they are oneboxed in chat" to "the team has chosen a pastebin service". xkcd is oneboxed in chat too; does that make it the official comic chosen by the team? Gist is only oneboxed because [somebody requested it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57041/gist-support-for-chat-onebox)

Comment: @Mrozek The asker wanted the team to implement a pastebin service that is oneboxed in chat, does syntax highlighting, is SE-only and has expiry options. I think "SE-only" is unnecessary and expiry options are plain bad here. The remainder has already been implemented by the team.

Comment: SO has no particular position on this; the onebox support for gist was added due to popular request, and was not *specifically* intended to act as a pastebin service. If that had been our intent, we would probably have just enabled pretty-print on code blocks.

Comment: @Marc: okay, rephrased.

Comment: +1 @badp for showing me gist.github.com

Comment: @MichaelMrozek If SO did have an official comic, it surely _would_ be xkcd?

Comment: Just a note - that example in the post contains images; apparently to add images, you'd have to clone, commit and push back (see [here](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/attaching-files-to-github-issues/)) - and it won't let you push back to the gist via `git` unless you pass `github` login auth (and unfortunately they don't accept OpenID); and once your anonymous gist is created on the web, you cannot edit it anonymously from the web either. I was otherwise overjoyed to hear (for the first time here) that gists are anonymous...