# Onebox support query

Tags: discussion, meta, onebox

There's a bunch of questions about adding chat onebox support for this, that, and the other.

- [ThinkGeek onebox support for chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142973/147191)
- [Add support for secure Wikipedia pages to Onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82029/147191)
- [Gist support for chat 'onebox'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57041/147191)

And then there's [a super-question about the same thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57288/147191), with various proposals as individual answers.

So if, for example, I want Wiktionary to be included in chat oneboxes, where should I post that? (What I've found so far is one answer about MediaWiki on the super-onebox question, with a comment about Wiktionary. Is upvoting that (which I have done) enough?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That super-question seems to be nothing more than an unofficial, light-hearted poll. I doubt that the development team is treating or has ever treated that question as an official suggestion box.

You should be posting a new question if you are serious about requesting onebox support for a Web site or Web service. I recommend [using the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=feature-request+chat+onebox) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[chat](/questions/tagged/chat)[onebox](/questions/tagged/onebox) when posting your request.

Comment: And [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147637/147191).